# Difference between model(x) and model.predict(x)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Here is a simple tensorflow functional API model.

```
input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,), dtype='float32')
output1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)(input1)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input1, outputs=output1)
```

In some examples of the functional API, output is obtained using model(), yet there is also model.predict().

With my example above, predict works:

```
model.predict([[[1.1, 2.2]]])
>> array([[1.8761028 , 0.20520687]], dtype=float32)
```

If I run just the model though, I get an error:

```
model([[[1.1, 2.2]]])
>> ... InvalidArgumentError: In[0] is not a matrix [Op:MatMul]
```

What is the difference and why is the error occuring?

Thanks,

Julian

Comment: Please link to examples where "output it obtained using model()".

Comment: Here's an example from the book Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras & Tensorflow (2nd edition) by Aurélion Géron. The notebook for Chapter 18 is here. https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/18_reinforcement_learning.ipynb .  If you search the page for "model(obs[np.newaxis])", you'll see where he is using this statement to obtain the network's prediction in order to calculate gradients for training.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error states `model()` expects a matrix as input, where you've provided a list.

**To solve this**, just convert it to a matrix:

```
model(tf.Variable([[[1.1, 2.2]]]))
```

or

```
model(np.array([[[1.1, 2.2]]]))
```

---

**On the difference between `model()` and `model.predict()`**

The code you are [referring to](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/214e675/18_reinforcement_learning.ipynb) where "output is obtained using model()":

```
left_proba = model(obs[np.newaxis])              # <--- HERE
action = (tf.random.uniform([1, 1]) > left_proba)
y_target = tf.constant([[1.]]) - tf.cast(action, tf.float32)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss_fn(y_target, left_proba))
```

This is similar to your 2nd line of code:

```
output1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)(input1)
```

How is this similar, you ask?

In *your* code, you create a new node in the graph of layers by calling a `Dense` layer on this `input1` object.
The "layer call" action is like drawing an arrow from `input1` to this layer you created.
You're "passing" the inputs to the dense layer, and out you get `output1`.

In the *reference* code, they treat `model` like a layer, and do a "layer call".
See the similarity?:

```
output     = Dense(input)
left_proba = model(obs[...])
```

In turn this creates new nodes that perform other operations (in the 3 lines that follow).
This is useful when you want to take an existing model and use it as a component (or "layer") to **build** another, new model.

As for model **inference**, you will always do this via `y = model.predict(x)`.

Comment: I understand your point that it is possible to treat a model like a layer. My question is about the difference between the output of a model when used that way, and when you call .predict(). In both cases, you are wanting the result from the model.

In my simple example, why does .predict() produce a result, but model() produce an error. If you want to use a model as part of another network using the functional API, you use Layer()(model). If you want the answer the model gives (which has the same neurons with the same weights and biases operating on the same data), you use .predict().

Comment: Oh, I see now. As the error states, `model()` expects a matrix as input, where you've provided a list. To solve this, just convert it to a matrix i.e. `model(tf.Variable([[[1.1, 2.2]]]))` or `model(np.array([[[1.1, 2.2]]]))`. I'll put this in the answer as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. That makes sense. I can see that the output from model() is a tensor, which is what's needed if you're going to use it as input to another model. i.e. Using the functional API. The .predict() method produces non-tensor results.